# Pika + RabbitMQ: setting basic_qos to prefetch=1 still appears to consume all messages in the queue

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, qos

I've got a python worker client that spins up a 10 workers which each hook onto a RabbitMQ queue. A bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
worker_count=10

def mqworker(queue, configurer):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='mqhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=qname, durable=True)
    channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=qname,no_ack=False)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.start_consuming()


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    doSomeWork();
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(worker_count):
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=mqworker)
        worker.start()
```

The issue I have is that despite setting basic_qos on the channel, the first worker to start accepts all the messages off the queue, whilst the others sit there idle. I can see this in the rabbitmq interface, that even when I set `worker_count` to be 1 and dump 50 messages on the queue, all 50 go into the 'unacknowledged' bucket, whereas I'd expect 1 to become unacknowledged and the other 49 to be ready.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I appear to have solved this by moving where `basic_qos` is called.

Placing it just after `channel = connection.channel()` appears to alter the behaviour to what I'd expect.

Comment: thank you! that did solve the issue. and btw this is very hard to debug..

Comment: @Hiagara yeah just ran into this today myself. Amazing that almost 5 years later this is still not clear or documented in the API.

Comment: I think that we should to declarate  `basic_qos` before `basic_consume`.  Because basic_consume use this setting when initialized.

Comment: agreed with @rborodinov. I had `basic_qos` right after `basic_consume` and it didn't work. Switched them, now it works fine.

Comment: I also had to set `auto_ack=False` when setting up the `basic_consume` for it to work. Otherwise it still consumed more messages than expected.

Comment: My `.ack()` was in the loop inside the callback, so it was trying to call it more than once for every `delivery_tag` thus resulting in a RabbitMQ 406 PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag.

Comment: @Tobias RE needing to set both `basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)` AND `auto_ack=False` is because of the AMQP spec ["The prefetch-count is ignored if the no-ack option is set"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.qos.prefetch-count). Please note: [In pika they use the word  `auto_ack`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_consume) and in the AMQP spec they use the word `no-ack`. kind of confusing IMO.